# How to read/write to nested Firebase Object in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am working with Angular and Firebase's Real Time Database. I am currently following the [AngularFire documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md) and am retrieving data as lists. I can't seem to figure out how to get a nested list from within a list.

Here is an example of my Firebase RTDB structure:

[image]

As per the documentation's guidance, I am able to access the Unique Key (which was created as a result of pushing to "items"), Item 1 and Item 2. I would like to know how to access "items/Item1/personality". How can I get the value of "temperament"? How can I update this value?

Here is the code I am using right now (which comes from the Documentation):

**app.component.ts**

```js
listRef!:AngularFireList<any>;
listItems!:Observable<any[]>;

constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.listRef = db.list('items');
    this.listItems = this.listRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c => (
          {key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()} 
        )))
    );
}

  //to add an item
  addItem(newName: string) {
    this.listRef.push({ text: newName });
  }

  //to update an item
  updateItem(key: string, newText: string) {
    this.listRef.update(key, { text: newText });
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of listItems | async">
    <input type="text" #updatetext [value]="item.text" />
    <button (click)="updateItem(item.key, updatetext.value)">Update</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="text" #newitem />
<button (click)="addItem(newitem.value)">Add</button>
```

I have seen some older solutions have recommended using `forEach()` function, however, I cannot find any documentation on how to use this with the `snapshotChanges()` function.

I realise that in this example the async pipe has been used. I believe this automatically handles the subscriptions. I am also wondering if I plan on updating the nested data, would I need to manually subscribe to the Observable?

Comment: Inside the `pipe` stick a `tap` so you have `.pipe(tap(data=>console.log(data)), map(...your map code))`. Post what you get.

Comment: Here is what I get: https://imgur.com/9uyj2oV.